# Integral involving delta functions and vector quantities

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, dirac-delta

This integral comes from equation (3.15) in an [older paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3719/1/6/319/meta) I've been reading:
$$
\int \mathrm{d} \Omega_k \, 
\delta\left(|\vec{k}|^2 - |\vec{k}+\vec{q}_1|^2\right)
\delta\left(|\vec{k}|^2 - |\vec{k}-\vec{q}_2|^2\right) .
$$
The integration over $\Omega_k$ refers to the angular coordinates of the vector $\vec{k}$. I'm most interested in the case of three spatial dimensions, for which
$$
\int \mathrm{d} \Omega_k 
\to
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^\pi d\varphi \sin \varphi,
$$
where $\theta$ and $\varphi$ are the azimuthal and polar angles associated with $\vec{k}$. The result should depend on the lengths $|\vec{k}|$, $|\vec{q}_1|$, and $|\vec{q}_2|$, as well as the dot product $\vec{q}_1\cdot\vec{q}_2$.

The authors write that the integral is straightforward and don't give an explicit result, so I suspect that I'm missing something simple. I've tried a few strategies, such as using integral representations for the delta functions, but I haven't yet found an elegant approach.

Comment: Using both $k$ and $\vec{k}$ makes the notation a little unclear. What is the $k$? Also what do you mean by $(\vec{k}+\vec{q}_1)^2$? It is equal to $\|\vec{k}+\vec{q}_1\|^2$?

Comment: Being used to physicists notation, I assume that $u^2 = \|\vec{u}\|^2$ and

Comment: I made some tweaks to the notation for clarity. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Does $\text d\Omega_k$ indicate integration over some sphere $\{ |k| = c \}$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor: yes, that's right.

Comment: I don't have time to make a proper attempt, but I feel like the difficulty should be in finding some change of variables to allow one of the diracs to depend only of one of the angular coordinates, so that it can be treated via the usual formulas eg. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function . Has this been your experience?

Comment: The best choice of coordinate system I've come up with so far involves aligning one of the q-vectors with the z-axis and the other in the x-z plane. This does "allow one of the diracs to depend only of one of the angular coordinates". I can post my progress in this direction a bit later.

Comment: I am unable to see how it is possible that in the Lebesgue sense this integral is not equal to $0$ or $\infty$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mucciolo I don't know what this integral is but I don't think it's infinite. It's a more complicated version of $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \delta(x)\delta(y) dxdy$, right?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Not really, since a sphere is a compact set. This integral will evaluate to $\infty$ if $q_1=0$ or $q_2=0$. Furthermore $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \delta(x)\delta(y) dxdy = 0$ in the Lebesgue sense because it differs of the zero function only in a null set. However I am aware that in some way it is possible to attribute the value of $1$ to it. Which makes me wonder what kind of integral is that.

Comment: @mucciolo the integral $\int_U \delta(x) dx$ is more commonly written in modern mathematics(i.e. not physics) as $$\int_U d\delta = \delta(U) = \begin{cases} 1 & 0 \in U \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$. The measure  whose null sets are relevant is not the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Oh! This really clarifies the things! Many thanks! Could you suggest a reference with a discussion on that?

Comment: @mucciolo not really, I cobbled what I know from a variety of resources. Knowing measure theory is a good start, you may also want to look for books on distribution theory. If I knew a good reference for working with integrals written in the physics style, I'd have written an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full solution (yet), but it's the closest I've come so far. I still think there is likely a more elegant approach. I will use the convention that $k = |\vec{k}|$.

#### Coordinate system (three dimensions)

Choose a spherical coordinate system for $\vec{k}$ such that $\vec{q}_1$ coincides with the positive $z$-axis, and let $\theta$ and $\varphi$ represent the azimuthal and polar angles associated with $\vec{k}$. Then, 
$$
\vec{k} \cdot \vec{q}_1 = k \, q_1 \cos \varphi .
$$

Rotate the coordinate system about the z-axis until $\vec{q}_2$ lies on the $x>0$ portion of the $x$-$z$ plane. Let $\alpha$ represent the angle between $\vec{q}_2$ and the $z$-axis. Then, using the formula for a [dot product in spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243142/what-is-the-general-formula-for-calculating-dot-and-cross-products-in-spherical),

$$
\vec{k} \cdot \vec{q}_2 = k \, q_2
\left[ \sin \varphi \sin \alpha \cos \theta + \cos \varphi \cos \alpha \right].
$$

The original integral may now be written
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^\pi d\varphi \, \sin \varphi \,\,
\delta\left(f(\varphi)\right) \delta\left(g(\theta,\varphi)\right)
$$

with

$$
f(\varphi) = 2k \, q_1\cos\varphi + q_1^2
$$

and

$$
g(\theta,\varphi) = 2kq_2
\left[ \sin \varphi \sin \alpha \cos \theta + \cos \varphi \cos \alpha \right]
-q_2^2.
$$

#### Evaluating the integral over $\varphi$

Using the [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function) suggested by Calvin Khor, we can say that

$$
\delta\left(f(\varphi)\right) \to
\frac{\delta(\varphi-\varphi_0)}{2k q_1 |\sin \varphi_0|}
$$

with $\varphi_0 = \arccos \left(-q_1 / 2k\right)$, which is valid for $q_1 \le 2k$. We can now evaluate the integral over $\varphi$, obtaining
$$
\frac{1}{2kq_1} \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \, g(\theta,\varphi_0)
$$

If $q_1 > 2k$, the integral evaluates to $0$.

#### Evaluating the integral over $\theta$

Work in progress...

Comment: Hey I think you're basically done, just that you have to integrate in $\theta $ first