# Dot product of a cartesian vector with a spherical vector

Tags: inner-products, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I have a vector of the form $P\hat{z}$ in the Cartesian system. I need to perform a dot product with another vector which is the spherical form. I figured it would be easier to convert $P\hat{z}$ into the spherical form and my immediate guess was the form would be $P\hat{r}$ with $\theta$ and $\phi$ zero meaning $\theta$ was "pointing" upwards or in the $z$ direction. As for $\phi$, any value should essentially give me the same thing.

This intuition appears to be clearly wrong. Deciding to use some of Mathematica's magic, I plugged in $(0,0,P)$ and attempted conversion from Cartesian to Spherical which threw the following error-

> ArcTan::indet: Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0,0] encountered.

And the output was-

$\{\sqrt{P^2},\tan ^{-1}(P,0),\text{Indeterminate}\}$

which is what I originally thought of.

**How do I perform a dot product with this when $\phi$ is indeterminate?**

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243142/what-is-the-general-formula-for-calculating-dot-and-cross-products-in-spherical

Comment: Perfect. Thanks